# Error on trying to run db:migrate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails. I created a model by running the rails g scaffold command, and then tried to run rails db:migrate in the wsl terminal which gave me this huge error:

```
rails db:migrate
/home/nidhi/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/log/development.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
   (0.6ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.3ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/Windows/system32/railsfriends/friends/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried unchecking the "Read only" property of the development.log file it mentions, but that did not help. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you create the database first? `rails db:create` then `rails db:migrate` or try `rails db:reset` will drop and recreate the database then run rails `db:migrate` to latest migration but when using create or reset options you will loose all data previously saved. Anyway a reset should sort you out

Comment: I just ran a "rails g scaffold friends eg_field:string.." in the terminal, which I'm assuming created the model table named friends

Comment: The scaffold creates all the files needed to generate the table plus the controller, views and model but the scaffold does not touch the database. For every new rails project once the database.yml is configured the way you want it, the default is fine until you decide to make use of postgresql or some other dbms, you need to create the database and `rails db:create` will do this. then you run the migrations generated by the scaffold which, as you have seen may well fail if the database has not been created properly in the first place

Comment: So just try `rails db:reset` then try migrating again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting my computer worked for me! I just had to go to my original folder and uncheck the "Read only" property, then restart the computer. The `rails db:migrate` command works now.

Comment: a reset would have sorted it without the need to reboot but glad you got it sorted